# Check if String has (9 digits) then

Tags: vb.net

Is there anything like

```
if abc.text = (some 9 digits/characeters) then

Endif
```

It should be exact 9 digits/characters then only it goes into the if statement...

Any Idea???

Comment: `abc.Text.Length = 9`

Comment: Oh, thanx, write in answer so I can upvote it.... @NicoSchertler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the length of your string equals 9:

```
If abc.Text.Length = 9 Then
    'ToDo
EndIf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to check the lenght us

```
If abc.text.Lenght = 9 Then

End IF
```

However if you want to contraint to only number or characters use reqular expression

```
Dim objRegExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}$")
If objRegExp.Match(abc).Success

End If
```

Do not forget to import:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim x As String = Console.ReadLine()
    If (x.Length = 9) Then
        Console.WriteLine("We have nine character")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("we have {0}  character .", x.Length)
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module